# how to use a filter using regex in Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, cfdirectory

New to coldfusion, new to regex...

I have a directory of files, named with "some" followed by a 13digit number, followed by underscore, ID and file ending like so:

```
  some0000000000000_ID.jpg
```

ID can be any string.

How would I get the ID using regex? I guess I'd be looking for something like this, which captures everything between the underscore and file ending dot:

```
  _\A[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*$
```

but I'm really not getting anywhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I ended up doing it like this, which is *hack-ish* but works nicely:

```
<cfset cropFront = #ListRest(ReReplaceNoCase(name, ".png|.jpg", ""), "_")#>
<cfset cropFull = #ListFirst(ReReplaceNoCase( cropFront, "xxxxx", ""), "." )#>
```

Maybe useful for someone else, too!

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution. The string parsing part is not really hackish. Note that enclosing the expression in `##` is not necessary. You need them only when you output expression results to the page and in certain few CF tags like `<cfdump var="#x#">` or `<cfloop collection="#x#">`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<cfdirectory name="images" directory="#path#" filter="some?????????????_ID.jpg">
```

The filter is not a regex pattern. It only knows the `?` and `*` wildcard characters.

Comment: but ID can be "house" or "a_very_long_word", will I still get that using just the filter?

Comment: Sure. `filter="some?????????????_*.jpg"` - You could use `ListFirst(name, "_")` to get the `some?????????????` part, and `ListRest(ReplaceNoCase(name, ".jpg", ""), "_")` to dissect the file name without regex.

Comment: Cool. That looks like something I can work with! Thank you very much... will be some time until I speak regex tough... ;-)

Comment: The list functions are generally pretty useful, you should look at the others, too. Often they can jump in as a better-than-regex solution for simple string processing.

Answer (score 2):

Can't test at the moment but this is the idea...

```
<cfdirectory name="files" directory="path" action="list" />

<cfloop query="files">
    <cfset findinfo = refind("^some(\d{13})_", files.name, 0, true) />
    <cfif arraylen(findinfo.pos) eq 2>
        <cfset fileid = mid(files.name, findinfo.pos[2], findinfo.len[2]) />
        <!--- do something --->
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This is very brittle. You ought to do a range check on the `findinfo` array.